# How to convert the vector <string> of the C++ type to the corresponding Ctype type in Python

Tags: python, c++, vector, visual-c++

How to convert the vector  of the C++ type to the corresponding Ctype type in Python

c++

```
extern "C" API void vector_string_test(string* data) {
vector<string> vec = {"123abc","456efg"};
std::memcpy(data, vec.data(), vec.size() * sizeof vec[0]);}
```

python

```
dll=dll.LoadLibrary(dll_path)
vector_string_test=dll.vector_string_test
vector_string_test.argtypes=(POINTER(ctypes.c_wchar_p),)
vector_string_test.restype=None
data=(c_wchar_p*2)()
vector_string_test(data)
data_ptr=cast(data,c_char_p)
print(data_ptr.value)
```

Then I get:

```
b'123abc'
```

So How I get all the results in vec with Python？

Comment: “C”types doesn’t work with c++ objects such as string, only C-compatible types.  How did you define `string` since it isn't clear if it is `std::string` or something else.  Make a [mcve].  Also, you pass in `(c_wchar_p*2)()` which is equivalent to `wchar_t*[2]` in C, but in C++ it looks like you are initializing with `char*` string values.  The pointers passed in are null as well, so memcpy to them will fail.  There's a lot wrong here.

Comment: Exporting C++ types on any API is not recommended. You might want to look at pybind (e.g. https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html)